# Unit testing Angular services in component-based architectures

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

my current approach is that I have two modules:

**dashboard**, where I keep `dashboard` component,

**core** where I have `alertsWarningsData` factory, connecting with backend

My current unit testing approach is explicitly overwriting this service:

**dashboard.component.js**

```
angular.
    module('dashboard').
    component('dashboard', {
        controller: DashboardController,
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html'
});

DashboardController.$inject = ['alertsWarningsData'];
function DashboardController(alertsWarningsData) {
    var vm = this;
    setAlertsWarnings();

function setAlertsWarnings() {
    return alertsWarningsData.getAlertsWarnings()
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.alertsWarnings = data;
            return data;
        });
}
```

**dashboard.component.spec.js**

```
describe('Dashboard component', () => {
    let $componentController;
    beforeEach(module('dashboard'));
    beforeEach(inject((_$componentController_) => {
        $componentController = _$componentController_;
    }));

    it(`should exist`, (inject(($q) => {
        // given
        let streamsData = {};
        let alertsWarningsData = {};
        alertsWarningsData.getAlertsWarnings = function() { return $q.defer().promise };

        // when
        const dashboardController = $componentController('dashboard', {'alertsWarningsData': alertsWarningsData});

        // then
        expect(dashboardController).toBeDefined();
    })));
});
```

Question: Is there any better way to mock this service? So I can do this in `beforeEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
beforeEach(module('dashboard', ($provide) => {
  $provide.factory('alertsWarningsData', ($q) => ({
    getAlertsWarnings: () => $q.resolve()
  }))
});
```

[`module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) has an object parameter for mocking services with `value`, but since a mocked service should be injected with `$q`, `$provide` may be used.

It is convenient that `$controller` and `$componentController` have an option to mock dependencies per controller, but it is not necessary to use this feature.

Comment: That's nice, but in solution from my question I'm able to set up `getAlertsWarnings` result for each test case - in order to test various situations. As far as I understand your solution, it enables only to pass this promise with the same result every time.

Comment: This is a typical task. A result may be assigned dynamically, it becomes `$q.resolve(aVariableFromParentFunctionScope)`.

Comment: And that's perfect now! Thanks!